# How can this computed be improved in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to return computed based on condition. However if condition fails I thought about returning null which is then becomes ugly in adding v-if as a resultt. Here is how does it look like:

```
   AreAllItemsAvailable() {
      const finalAvailableItems = this.allItems.filter(
        item => this.availableItems.includes(item.id),
      )
      if (finalAvailableItems.length) {
        return finalAvailableItems.every(item => item.count === '1')
      } else {
        return null
      }
    },
```

Then in the template, I have such a thing:

```
v-if= "AreAllItemsAvailable !=null && !AreAllItemsAvailable"
```

How this can be improved?

Comment: `v-if="!AreAllItemsAvailable"` would catch both, but you should just return `false` instead of `null` anyway. "AreAllItemsAvailable" is a yes/no question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` method if it doesn't find any matched item it returns an empty array `[]`, so you could keep one filter method that returns an array (filled or empty) and iterate over it :

```
 AreAllItemsAvailable() {
     return this.allItems.filter(
        item => this.availableItems.includes(item.id) && item.count === '1',
      )

}
```

in template :

```
 v-for="item in AreAllItemsAvailable"
```

Comment: One more thing related to the above answer. Did first computed work for this?: this.available items is just an array of ids [0, 1, 2, 3,...] e.g. while this.allItems is Array of objects so basicaly it should filter all available items that the simple array has which is matching the ids of array of objects. I am not sure if includes part is correct

Comment: in console returns undefined for filtering part that's why I have some thoughts about that part

Comment: could you reproduce a simple code in codepen or any online playground?

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Can you please check this question as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236124/filter-is-not-working-inside-the-action-for-filtering-array-of-objects-in-vuex

Answer (score 0):

To clean, you could add an intermediary computed value :

```
finalAvailableItems() { 
    return this.allItems.filter(
            item => this.availableItems.includes(item.id)
          )
    }

AreAllItemsAvailable() {
        return this.finalAvailableItems.every(item => item.count === '1');
    },
```

No need to return a null value : if your objective is to check if all items are available, the boolean `AreAllItemsAvailable` will return False if `finalAvailableItems` is empty

```
v-if= "!AreAllItemsAvailable"
```

Comment: One more thing related to the above answer. Did first computed work for this?:

this.available items is  just an array of ids  [0, 1, 2, 3,...] e.g. while this.allItems is Array of objects so basicaly it should filter all available items that the simple array has which is matching the ids of array of objects

Comment: I think you commented the wrong answer, don't you ?