# Filter is not working inside the action for filtering array of objects in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have an array of objects which is getter. I am using getter inside action and trying to filter it but whatever I do filtering doesn't work and it returns all mapped item ids.

```
filterItems({ getters, commit }) {
  let filteredItems = getters.getAllItems
    .filter(item => item.type !== 'hat' || item.type !== 'glases')
    .map(item => item.id)
  console.log(filterItems)
  commit('setFilteredItems', filteredItems)
},
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Seems like `getAllItems` should be invoked. try `getAllItems().filter...`

Comment: @SagiRika getters are properties not methods

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Can the reason be that getter is getting changed and action can not track that change? Or filter itself is wrong?

Comment: did you try to separate them?

Comment: Yes, I want to update the state with a filtered array of objects. So the state will have only the filtered results

Comment: So state will contain only objects that don't have those product types which are filtered.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim do you mean separating the chaining e.g. filter the getter and store in variable then map it and stor in other var?

Comment: let's say that the state name is `items` which contains 10 items and you want to override it by the filtered item which are 6 for example?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea, I suggest to add another state named  `filteredItems` and keep the origin `items`

Comment: The reason of replacing is that it's kind of resetting because of otherwise array regularly grows. It's kind of clean up. That's why I want to change original state.

Comment: Anyway filtering doesn't work while the goal is mutating the original array

Comment: could you prepare some running code in codepen? in order to debug it

Comment: why not just have another getter that returns filtered items?  You only need the action if it is async or needs to call other actions or mutations.  no point storing a computed filter in state...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is coming from here:

```
item.type !== 'hat' || item.type !== 'glases'
```

1. This always returns `true` because `item.type` will never be equivalent to `'hat'` and `'glases'` at the same time.
2. I doubt that `'glases'` is a correct spelling? This might be a problem or just a mis-typing

Comment: So should I use && here?

Comment: I don't know what you want. Do you want to return items that are not 'hat' and 'glasses'? If so, && should do the job

Comment: Please let me know if you have solved your problem =))

Comment: Sure I will check it